# Crafting items using MineCraft Forge 1.12

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

Since forge has changed from 1.18/1.11 to 1.12, I need some examples of how to code with the new framework in regards to tools/weopons

Answer (score 0):

After a painful trial of trying to figure out how to register items in the new version of Forge for 1.12, I have attached a link to my Github repository that outlines how to register new items, jsut go to the link below:
[Minecraft forge 1.12 crafting project](https://github.com/lionel5116/MineCraftForge112)

Forge from version 1.8 - 1.12 has changed a lot.
Hope this helps

Comment: You can delete the example mod from your project / git repo. You do not need to include your mod ID when setting the registry name: Forge takes care of that for you (and prevents typos from breaking things). For item models, use a parent of `"item/generated"` for most items, this supplies the "display" tags for you. For tools, you can use `"item/handheld"` (again, the parent supplies the display tags). You are using pack meta version 3, which means your lang file should be named in all-lower-case, e.g. `en_us.lang`.  Additionally, to prevent a link-only answer, include the relevant code here.

Comment: How to do this can also be found in the [Minecraft Forge Documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
I must admit though the link from [Registering an Item](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/items/items/#registering-an-item) to [Registering Things](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/registries/#registering-things) is not very visible.